# Populating 2D Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, firebase

I am trying to popoulate a 2D array using Firebug API,

```
var sites = [];
    var siteCounter = 0;

    //Firebase API Calls

    var messageListRef = new Firebase('https://my.firebaseio.com');
    messageListRef.once('value', function(allMessagesSnapshot) {
      allMessagesSnapshot.forEach(function(messageSnapshot) {
        var latitude = messageSnapshot.child('latitude').val();
        var longitude = messageSnapshot.child('longitude').val();
        sites[siteCounter][0] = 'siteCounter';
        sites[siteCounter][1] = latitude;
        sites[siteCounter][2] = longitude;
        sites[siteCounter][3] = siteCounter;
        sites[siteCounter][4] = 'This is siteCounter.';

        siteCounter++;
        alert(sites[siteCounter][1]  + " " + sites[siteCounter][2] );
      });
    });
```

But this breaks for sites[siteCounter][0] and says it is undefined. Any clue how to work with this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want 2D array, you must to initialize like this :

```
var tab = new Array();
```

after

```
tab[0] = new Array();
```

Try this code

```
sites[siteCounter] = new Array(); 
sites[siteCounter][0] = 'siteCounter';
sites[siteCounter][1] = latitude;
sites[siteCounter][2] = longitude;
sites[siteCounter][3] = siteCounter;
sites[siteCounter][4] = 'This is siteCounter.';
```

or directly

```
sites[siteCounter] = new Array("siteCounter", latitude, longitude, siteCounter, "This is siteCounter.");
```

Comment: problem is i am loosing all the values outside the foreach loop

Comment: you are sure? because in this example that I have write in jsFiddle, I don't loose my values http://jsfiddle.net/UdD2L/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a 
`sites[siteCounter] = [];`
before `sites[siteCounter][0]`?

I assume you have to declare it as an array to be able to put stuff in the array.